# Deleting a row in a Pandas Dataframe adds a column to the Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, flask

I want to delete a single row in a dataframe which gets generated based on a csv, and after the row gets deleted, the file should be saved again. But I have the problem, that everytime I delete a row, a column with the name "Unknown 0.x" gets added and I have no idea why. Here is my delete function:

```
def delete_row(path, file_type, row):
    if file_type == 'csv':
        df = pd.read_csv(path)
        df.drop(row, inplace=True)
        df.to_csv(path)
```

[image: This is the datafram after I deleted 2 rows:]

I tried different approaches for deleting a row, even with converting it into other file types first. And when I try this with .json or .txt the deletion works. Only with .csv I have this problem

Comment: When you write the csv file, the index is being written as well (0, 1, 2, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because every time you use `df.to_csv()`, the index is saved as a new column. You need to set `index=False` to solve the problem. So your function would become:

```
def delete_row(path, file_type, row):
    if file_type == 'csv':
        df = pd.read_csv(path)
        df.drop(row, inplace=True)
        df.to_csv(path, index=False) # --> You need to set index to false here
```

---

On a related note, if you have an index column in your csv file that you want to set as index, assign that column as index while reading the csv file. For example:

```
pd.read_csv(path, index_col=0)
```